# Finding PayPal Buy Now Button redirection link

Tags: paypal

I am trying to make a program that can scrape a site and search for PayPal buy now button redirection links.

I can scrape the site but I realize that when you hit the button, it does not contain the URL that you will be redirected to make purchase.  How would I go about finding the button redirection link, or even how would I have the site scrape and click on the button to at least have the redirect site appear?  Would I somehow have to make the scraper hit the form and submit?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /><br />
<input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="PUEGWVJXLH4FQ" /><br />
<input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" /><br />
<img loading="lazy" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">_______________________________________________________</p>
</form>
```

Comment: The redirection link is in the `action` parameter of the `form`: `action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`.

Comment: "Would I somehow have to make the scraper hit the form and submit?": yes.

Comment: @user207421 got it thanks for the information.  Would you recommend using Selenium or is beautifulsoup better for this task?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.paypal.co/buttons, log in, and (after logging in) create a new simple Buy Now button with **no dropdown options nor text fields** (which require HTML) -- and once the button is created and you are viewing the generated code, switch over to the "E-mail" tab above it.

The link in that E-mail tab will have a hosted button ID, which you can swap out / use to dynamically generate the Buy Now "redirection link" you're asking for. When loaded in a browser, that link will initiate a checkout, same as clicking the button.

---

There are several other types of PayPal payment buttons, including:

- Unhosted Buy Now buttons (which are not saved at PayPal, and do not have a hosted_button_id). These buttons use a redirection link or form post that will [include HTML variables](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/) to set up the payment.
- Newer smart buttons, generated via https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart or similar -- these do not have redirection URL, and instead use JS to open a mini window for payment approval.

---

Another way to construct a working URL is to begin with the form's action parameter `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`, add `?` to begin a GET string, and add all the inputs from the form that have a `name`, in with the syntax `name=value`, separated by '&' .... so for example:

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?hosted_button_id=PUEGWVJXLH4FQ&anothername=anothervalue&...`

Comment: thanks for your response. I wanted to make a bot to help purchase some things that sell out fast.  I assume that the redirection link must be hidden then.  Would the next best direction be to attempt selenium to click on the buy now button?

Comment: Nothing is hidden, all the information for redirection is in the form.

Comment: Would that indicated, i need to submit the form to get redirected since there is no link?

Comment: No, see the answer above for how to generate a link. All the necessary parameters are in the form

Comment: I went ahead and created the button, i see that the value generated by the button is much longer than the value in the site form above.  In addition, the email link has no discernible information which makes it link to the html form code.  Not sure of the correlation of my generated redirection site vs his.  Will it be impossible to determine because the code can be "encrypted"

Comment: Log in before creating a button.

Comment: i edited my question.  I created the button logged in and pasted the URL along with the HTML.  Hmm i guess I am not seeing correlation.  Also, webdev, is a weakness of mine.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He wants to scrape existing pages, not create new buttons.

Comment: Creating a button is the most straightforward way to see a working link with values that can be substituted. I've extended my answer for those not able to create or substitute into a working link for some reason.

Comment: There is nothing in your answer that identifies the button-click URL, which is the question that was asked.

Comment: A URL can be obtained by either creating a button or putting together the input variables, as detailed in the answer.